# Редирект на null после отправки формы

Tags: php, html

Отправляю форму[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

После отправки формы кидает на 404 страницу.
В чем проблема ? Файл send.php в корне сайта

```
          <form action="/send.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="input-phone" name="input-phone" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона">
      <input type="text" id="input-name" name="input-name" placeholder="Ваше имя" style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <input type="hidden" id="input-ip" name="input-ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="input-host" name="input-host" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>">
      <button type="submit" name="sendCallback" id="submit-modal">Отправить</button>
  </form>
```

Обработчик:

```
if(isset($data['sendCallback'])) {

$thisPhone = $data['input-phone'];
$checkUserIsset = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `tobook` WHERE `phone` = '$thisPhone'" );
$rowUser = mysqli_num_rows($checkUserIsset);
if($rowUser > 0) {
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    $arrayData = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `tobook` WHERE `phone` = '$thisPhone'" );
    $arrayDB = mysqli_fetch_array($arrayData);
    $message = "Обратный звонок\n\n"."(Забронировал)\nИмя: ".$arrayDB['name']."\nТелефон: ".$arrayDB['phone']."\nГород: ".$arrayDB['city']."\nУслуга: ".$arrayDB['service']."\nДата: ".$arrayDB['date']."\nСайт: ".$arrayDB['site'];
    $bot->send($message);
    return header("Location: https://".$data['input-host']."/"); 
}
$message = "Обратный звонок\n\n"."Телефон: ".$data['input-phone']."\nИмя: ".$data['input-name']."\nСайт: ".$data['input-host']."\nГород: ".$data['input-city'];
$bot->send($message);
return header("Location: https://".$data['input-host']."/");
```

}

Comment: Выложите ваш код в сниппет, зачем выкладывать код картинкой...?

Comment: Исправил.Надеюсь поможете

Comment: Остальные данные приходят? проблема только с редиректом?

Comment: На других сайтах все отлично с таким же кодом, тут же редирект идет на 404 ошибку, хотя url в action настоящий и файл по нему есть.
Как я понял, форма даже на send.php файл не отправляет запрос, а сразу на null редирект идет

Answer (score 0):

Проверь, скрипт приходит на обработчик, допустим, просто добавь txt в каталог. И в форме пропиши путь нормально, через $_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

button всегда редиректил на 404
input(type submit) - все отлично отправляет.
Все равно спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: Вы можете отметить свой ответ галочкой